# How to check Scientific Notation is present or not Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
def fun(number):
   #Here in  I want to check scientific notation or not 

   if type(number)==int or type(number)==float :
       do something
```

SO as you can see above example I want to check whether a number has Scientific notation or not before another if condition.

Comment: You mean if `number` is a string? If not, it doesn't have any notation.

Comment: Scientific notation is not a type of number. It's a way of displaying a number. It's not meaningful to ask whether a number "has scientific notation".

Comment: The notation used for a number is something determined when you render it to a string. You can choose to have it in scientific notation or not.

Comment: `numpy` automatically uses scientific notation to display an array if the numerical range of the elements is wide enough, eg. for `np.array([.0012, 123])` the display is `array([1.20e-03, 1.23e+02])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point numbers may be represented as scientific notation when converted to or from a string, so it's only useful to discuss whether the string representation of a number is in scientific notation or not. The number itself is internally just a binary floating point number following [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory).

If you want to determine if a string represents a floating point number, the easiest way is simply to try to convert it, and catch the error if it can't be converted:

```
usr_input = input("enter a number")
try:
    float(usr_input)
except:
    print("input is not a valid floating point number")
```

Then if the string represents a floating point number, you can test if it has an `"e"` in it to tell if it's scientific notation:

```
if 'e' in usr_input.lower(): #convert to lower case so we don't have to also check for "E"
    print("scientific notation")
```

Comment: of note: iirc the default string format for `str(some_float)` is dependent on the operating system. It's usually all quite similar, but [not perfectly the same](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/test/test_tokenize.py#L983).

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned before, scientific notation is not a type - it is a representation.
if you wish to return the scientific notation of some value `num`, you can use `{:.2e}.format(num)`, where `.2` indicates 2 decimal points, and `e` represents scientific notation
(for general use, you can discard the `.2`)

Comment: if number = 1.3577e-05, is there any way I check number has e or not ?

Comment: if `number `is a string you can check `e in number `

Comment: not for float or int ?

Comment: int or floats does not contain letters in them